# How to make an http request from an iOS app through api

Tags: ios, database, api, httprequest

I am using xcode to make an app that will allow the user to search through a database. This is the goodzer.com database and i want to know how to put their API into an http request within an ios app. Please anything will help.

Comment: Have you read the official documents?  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000165i

Answer (score 4):

Use a framework like [RestKit](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit) or [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking). They are both really easy to use and lets you connect to RESTful API:s in no time.

You will need to sign up for an API key through their website.

Searching through their database would look something like this (using AFNetworking):

```
NSString url = @"http://api.goodzer.com/products/v0.1/search_in_store/?storeId=fAfVfDCd&query=ipad+case&priceRange=20:50&apiKey=<Your_API_key>";
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager GET:url parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

This would return something like:

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "realtime_availability": true,
    "products_found": 199,
    "products": [
        {
            "id": 1573967503,
            "title": "Harley-Davidson - Envelope Case for Apple iPad, iPad 2 and iPad (3rd Genera ion) - Black",
            "price": 34.99,
            "url": "http://www.bestbuy.com/site/Harley-Davidson+-+Envelope+Case+for+Apple%AE+iPad%AE%2C+iPad+2+and+iPad+(3rd+Generation)+-+Black/5422949.p?id=1218643212507&skuId=5422949&cmp=RMX&ky=2nOYnsgAdnUUUygixM6IZsxTJF3fsquqM",
            "image": "http://img.goodzer.com/peregimator/?size=medium&valign=center&sign=d4e70e4e&image=http%3A//images.bestbuy.com/BestBuy_US/images/products/5422/5422949_sc.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id": 1573970162,
            "title": "Samsonite - Shuttle Case for Apple iPad, iPad 2 and iPad (3rd Generation) - Black/White",
            "price": 39.99,
            "url": "http://www.bestbuy.com/site/Samsonite+-+Shuttle+Case+for+Apple%AE+iPad%AE%2C+iPad+2+and+iPad+(3rd+Generation)+-+Black/White/5763475.p?id=1218692161151&skuId=5763475&cmp=RMX&ky=2nOYnsgAdnUUUygixM6IZsxTJF3fsquqM",
            "image": "http://img.goodzer.com/peregimator/?size=medium&valign=center&sign=9ac997a0&image=http%3A//images.bestbuy.com/BestBuy_US/images/products/5763/5763475_sc.jpg"
        },
    ...
    ]
}
```

Comment: Yes, but how would i connect that to goodzer.com's database through the api?

Comment: I really appreciate the code but which AFnetworking file would i implement that into?

Comment: You implement that in whatever file you want. Not in AFNetworking though. I suggest reading up on using external frameworks if you are uncertain on how to do it.

Comment: i tried the api url you gave me and it gave me this error 2013-11-09 20:37:23.056 NetworkingIsFun[2338:60b] Request Failed with Error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1000 "bad URL" UserInfo=0x17e40650 {NSUnderlyingError=0x17e3fac0 "bad URL", NSLocalizedDescription=bad URL}, {
    NSLocalizedDescription = "bad URL";
    NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1000 \"bad URL\" UserInfo=0x17e3fb00 {NSLocalizedDescription=bad URL}";
}

Comment: I was copying http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk_afnetworking/ tutorial. I tried implementing the api and it didnt work, please help.

Comment: Did you enter your own app key?

Comment: I posted my code here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19885716/afnetworking-substitution-for-goodzer please help me, thanks